# Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory

Tags: rhel, vmware

I've installed VMWare Player 6.0.1 build - 1379776 on a Red Hat Enterprise linux Server release 6.1 Beta ( Santiago ). When I attempt to start my virtual machine, I get the following the error:

```
  Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
  Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

`uname -r`

```
2.6.32-122.el6.x86_64
```

When I install vmmon I get the following error:

`sudo modprobe vmmon`

```
FATAL: Error inserting vmmon (/lib/modules/2.6.32-122.el6.x86_64/misc/vmmon.ko):    Invalid module format
```

My 2nd question is:

When I install it with `vmware-modconfig –console –install-all` I get the following error. How can I install all these packages?

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module": libpk-gtk-module.so: cannot open    shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-9282.log
Icon name must be set.
```

Comment: see this <https://communities.vmware.com/thread/245998?start=0&tstart=0>
Scroll until you found the correct Answer

Answer (score 3):

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

The complete article:
http://blog.nowherelan.com/2014/12/03/vmware-workstation-10-error-could-not-open-devvmmon-no-such-file-or-directory-please-make-sure-that-the-kernel-module-vmmon-is-loaded/

Comment: This is the easiest way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare player and workstation comes with Linux drivers, You need to install to get `/dev/vmmon`.

You can find `linux.iso` on installed directory. Run `vmware-config.pl` instead of rpm installation.

It will compile the two modules vmmon and vmnet which are require to run a virtual machine. I rather use tar.gz or tar.bz2 files instead of RPM files.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem. then disabling secure boot worked for me. 
try the following

**disable UEFI Secure Boot**

restart+Shift key
Go to Boot Manager and disable the option Secure Boot.

```
Change the UEFI boot order according to the medium you want to boot the computer
```

https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1811

Comment: How is this supposed to be an answer to the question?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/199590)

Comment: @Jeff thanks for guiding me to improve answer. I have edited it.