# "Could not open dev/vmmon" error - every time I start my VMware workstation starts

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, mx-linux

I use VMware Workstation 16 on my MX Linux. Each time I start it after starting my machine, I get the following error: "could not open /dev/vmmon". Yesterday and again today, I tried to solve this by following the steps mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99388/could-not-open-dev-vmmon-no-such-file-or-directory). The issue temoporarily gets solved, but it arises again whenever I start my laptop.
Is there any workaround to this problem which can be treated as a permanent solution? Thanks in advance.